# How to convert/package SVG files into an OTF/TTF font?

Tags: svg, fonts, truetype, cjk, opentype

I'm thinking about using Droid font to create a [Ruby-like](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/ruby/) font for CJK scripts.

However I'm not sure if I can create a **script to convert/package multiple SVG files/glyphs into one font file?**

### "New" glyphs creation

For information, I want to create new glyphs –for CJK glyhs– as follow:

1. put a Chinese glyph (e.g. *中*) into a SVG file ;
2. add the prononciation (e.g. *zhōng*) to this SVG.
3. Once all new CJK glyphs have been created in SVG, I need to package my font

Data would come from [Unihan datadase](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/Unihan.html).

## Goal

I want something similar to the image below but placing the pronunciation to another place and having different orientation.

[image: End result]

Comment: check out this [tutorial](http://blog.hull.io/post/47939445232/reconciling-svg-and-icon-fonts) There is a lot of eyeballing that goes into making a font that will look good on a screen. this [article](https://www.typotheque.com/articles/hinting) lays out the issues pretty nicely.

Comment: Actually the design/hinting process should already be done as I just want to update the plan related to CJK

Comment: The first link shared by @miah is dead :( [Use this cached version on the wayback machine instead.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150318004056/http://blog.hull.io/post/47939445232/reconciling-svg-and-icon-fonts)

Answer (score 1):

FontForge has a Python interface. http://fontforge.org/python.html

A glyph object has methods like `export` and `importOutlines`.
My code is untested but reading the FontForge docs the export should go like this:

```
import fontforge
f = fontforge.open("SomeChineeseFont.ext")

# Not sure if this is the right way to select all glyphs. But you'll get there.
for i in f.selection.select.all(): 
    f[i].export("%s.svg" %i)
```

Now after weeks of editing SVG's (automate this too). It's time to import:

```
import fontforge
f = fontforge.open("SomeChineeseFont.ext") # Use the orginal font as base

for i in f.selection.select.all(): 
    # Delete the original glyph or make sure your SVG 
    # only contains the contours you want to add.
    f.clear() 
    f[i].importOutlines("%s.svg" %i)

f.save("SomeRubyLikeChineeseFont.ext")
```

Is this what you where looking for?

Comment: I get an error `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'all'`. Is this no longer a way to get all glyphs?

Comment: I think it's simpler than the code above. It works to just use `for i in f:`